# How do I output spacy result separately for each file?

Tags: python, spacy

I am using the following python code to output organization names in the files in a directory on my computer

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') 
my_path = "/path/to/file/directory"
files = os.listdir(my_path)
myset = []

for file in files:
    newpath = (os.path.join(my_path, file)) 
    newpath1 = textract.process(newpath)
    newpath2 = newpath1.decode("utf-8")
    doc = nlp(newpath2)
    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent.label_=="ORG":
             myset.append(ent.text) 

print(myset)
```

This outputs the following:

```
['Apple', 'Tesla', 'Ford', 'Honda', 'IBM', 'Microsoft', 'Walmart', 'McDonalds']
```

The problem with this is that it does not separate results by file. It takes organization names from all files and puts them in ONE list. Ideally, I want my results grouped by file. For example, something like this:

```
[(Apple, Tesla), (Ford, Honda), (IBM), (Microsoft, Walmart, McDonalds)]
```

EDIT: Found the answer and posted it below. Shout out to user @AMC

Comment: Can you clarify what the issue is? Couldn't you create a list for each file, append the names to that list, and at the end of the `for file in files` loop add that list to the "main" one?

Comment: @AMC Got it. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, Thanks to User @AMC. I created a list for each file, appended organization names to that list and then added each list to the main list like so:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm') 
my_path = "/path/to/directory"
files = os.listdir(my_path)
myset = []

for file in files:
    newpath = (os.path.join(my_path, file)) 
    newpath1 = textract.process(newpath)
    newpath2 = newpath1.decode("utf-8")
    doc = nlp(newpath2)
    subset = []
    for ent in doc.ents:
        if ent.label_=="ORG":
             subset.append(ent.text) 

    myset.append(subset)

print(myset)
```